# How change resolution and update window without flickering

Tags: c++, winforms, window

I need to change the resolution different times and keep update the windows.

Actually I use this code:

```
    bool SetDiplayResolution(int Width, int Height, int Refresh = 0)
    {
        LONG Outout;
    
        DEVMODE desiredMode;
        memset(&desiredMode, 0, sizeof(desiredMode));
        desiredMode.dmSize = sizeof(desiredMode);
    
        if (EnumDisplaySettings(NULL, ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS, &desiredMode) != 0)
        {
            desiredMode.dmSize = sizeof(DEVMODE);
            desiredMode.dmPelsWidth = Width;
            desiredMode.dmPelsHeight = Height;
    
            if (Refresh > 0)
            {
                desiredMode.dmDisplayFrequency = Refresh;
                desiredMode.dmFields = DM_PELSHEIGHT | DM_PELSWIDTH | DM_DISPLAYFREQUENCY;
            }
            else
            {
                desiredMode.dmFields = DM_PELSHEIGHT | DM_PELSWIDTH;
            }
    
            Outout = ChangeDisplaySettings(&desiredMode, 0);
    
        }
    
        return Outout;
    }


void myfunction
{

    HWND hWnd = GetActiveWindow();

    SetDiplayResolution(1920, 1080);

    SetWindowPos(hWnd, 0, 0, 0, 1920, 1080, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOACTIVATE);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);
}
```

This code work fine but unfortunatenly the transaction beetween the old and new resolution produce some very short, but visble annoyng effects:

1. Temporary presence of the windows bar.
2. The screen flash for one instant.

I don't known if exist a way to solve. I have seen in some forum that other create a secondary top most window in order to avoid these side effects and then destroy this secondary window.

I don't sure if this is a good way.

Unfortunatenly I don't have access to window events becouse my is a dll (I have not create the window, but I have the handle).

Can you please help me ?

Thanks !

Comment: That's going to be hard I think. You may come _close_ but you have drivers and the hardware that needs to do this transition. Interesting question though. _Why_ do you need to change the resolution (more than once)?

Comment: Some flickering is unavoidable as the monitor detects and adapts to the new resolution. The video card also has to reconfigure memory, and the screen needs to be redrawn by Windows (these last two are helped by having a black secondary window cover everything).

Comment: Why do you need to change the resolution (more than once) ? I need to solve a bug to an external application that play different movie with wrong resoluton.